# HTML5 FileReader, read from local file

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I want to read a local binary file. So, I do this

```
var file = new File([""], url);
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function () {
    parse(reader.result);
}

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

where url is a filepath like url="c:\temp\myfile.bin"

I don't have any errors, but something is wrong, because all data from my app disappear. What could be wrong ? Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: What does "all data from my app disappear" mean? What data?

Comment: no warnings or errors

Comment: I think the reader only works with a `input type="file"`

Comment: You're misunderstanding how the File API works... It's a sandboxed area of the browser to read user-input(files) or content from the web and save it locally for later usage. Think of it as persistent cache...

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have to use **input type="file"** for security reasons.

Here's a working example. For convenience it shows the opened file in the same browser window.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function readFile() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        file = document.getElementById("uploadText").files[0];
        reader.onload = function (ev) {
          document.getElementById("obj").data = ev.target.result;
          // parse(ev.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        // reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      };
    </script>
    <div>
      <input id="uploadText" type="file" onchange="readFile();" />
    </div>
  <object id="obj" data="" />
</body>
</html>
```